# Plot a centered circle

Tags: code-golf, math, graphical-output

## Intro

Given radius \$r\$, draw a circle in the center of the screen.

[Sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19221/80214)

## The Challenge

Here is a simple challenge.

Plot a circle using the formula \$x^2+y^2=r^2\$, or any other formula that will plot a circle according to the given parameters.

You may use any units that your language provides, so long as they are well defined and give consistent output.

The circle must have it's center at the center of the canvas, and must have a padding of 5 units or more on all sides.

The circle can have any fill that does not match the outline.

You may have axes in the background of your plot.

The outline of the circle must be solid (no gaps), and it must be visible.  Here is an example:

[image]

Input can be taken in any acceptable form. (function params, variables, stdin...)

Output can be in the form of a separate window, or an image format.

Standard loopholes and rules apply.

## Example Code (`Java + Processing`)

```
// Modified from the C language example from
// https:// en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm
int r = 70; //radius
void settings() {
  size(2*r+10, 2*r+10);
}
 
void draw() {
  background(255);
  drawCircle(width/2, height/2, r, 60);
  save("Circle.png");
}

 
void drawCircle(int x0, int y0, int radius, int angle) {
  int circCol = color(0, 0, 0);
  float limit = radians(angle);
  int x = radius;
  int y = 0;
  int err = 0;
 
  while (x >= y && atan2(y, x) < limit) {
    set(x0 + x, y0 + y, circCol);
    set(x0 + y, y0 + x, circCol);
    set(x0 - y, y0 + x, circCol);
    set(x0 - x, y0 + y, circCol);
    set(x0 - x, y0 - y, circCol);
    set(x0 - y, y0 - x, circCol);
    set(x0 + y, y0 - x, circCol);
    set(x0 + x, y0 - y, circCol);
 
    y += 1;
    if (err <= 0) {
      err += 2*y + 1;
    }
    if (err > 0) {
      x -= 1;
      err -= 2*x + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

## Scoring

This is a [graphical-output](/questions/tagged/graphical-output) question. No ascii art.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the thickness of the outline must be 1 unit'? Are the units of outline thickness the same as those of the radius?

Comment: yes, it doesn't make sense. I changed it.

Comment: Are we allowed to let the input parameters be a bounding rectangle for it?

Comment: no, radius will be the only input @LiefdeWen

Comment: @Sisyphus if it is unavoidable, surely.

Comment: Do you think I should allow axes on any language? It might make more sense, so long as there is no fill for the circle. @Sisyphus

Comment: Fine, I'll add to the question that axes are allowed.

Comment: [Related (Draw a Polygon)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25885/76162)

Comment: You say there should be a padding of 5 units, what should happen if radius is bigger than  window size?

Comment: do as the other answers have done. zoom out and show the circle.

Comment: It isn't completely obvious to me that calling a function like ```plot_my_circle()``` or similar actually adheres to the requirement to "use ... any other formula", but I'm also (partly) guilty of this in my own answer...

Comment: the consensus at the sandbox was to allow any program that plotted a circle that followed the guidelines correctly, so it is fine.

Comment: If we can zoom, wouldn't the same constant-sized circle, not showing axes, work for any input?

Comment: That was an oversight, sorry. Input radius will not be bigger than window size. The answers that do have zooming show axes, so if there are axes with units on them, zooming is fine.

Answer (score 11):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 1 byte

`r`

[Try it on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/catcq7tqc3)

Uses the same input method as the other Desmos answer. An unused variable named `r` defaults to drawing a circle with radius r.

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>74</s> <s>70</s> <s>68</s> <s>65</s> 54 bytes

*Edit: -11 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(r)plot(r*1i^(1:1e3/99),,"l",l<-c(-r-5,r+5),l)
```

[Try it at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=plot_circle%3D%0Afunction(r)plot(r*1i%5E(1%3A1e3%2F99)%2Ct%3D%22l%22%2Cxlim%3Dl%3C-c(-r-5%2Cr%2B5)%2Cylim%3Dl)%0Aplot_circle(5))

I propose 3 possible answers to this challenge in [R](https://www.r-project.org/), of decreasing length but with increasing caveats.

My favourite answer (above, using `plot`) is the <s>middle</s> shortest one of the 3.  It plots a circle by calculating the complex coordinates of powers of `i`, using 396 points (with a bit of wrap-around).  Here's an image of the output from `plot_circle(5)`:

[image]

---

For a 'true' circle (rather than an almost-circle with tiny straight-lines connecting the data points), we can use the `curve` function with a formula, but unfortunately we need to draw the positive & negative halves separately, so it ends up longer:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>86</s> 84 bytes

```r
function(r){curve((r^2-x^2)^.5,xli=l<-c(-r-5,r+5),yli=l)
curve(-(r^2-x^2)^.5,add=T)}
```

[Try it at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=plot_circle%3D%0Afunction(r)%7Bcurve((r%5E2-x%5E2)%5E.5%2Cxli%3Dl%3C-c(-r-5%2Cr%2B5)%2Cyli%3Dl)%0Acurve(-(r%5E2-x%5E2)%5E.5%2Cadd%3DT)%7D%0Aplot_circle(5))

---

<s>The shortest (that I can think of)</s> Previously the shortest, but - thanks to Giuseppe now no longer so - is to use the `circles` option of the `symbols` function, for only 56 bytes.  However, this has the caveat that the circle symbols are always circular even if the plot is re-sized, and so may no-longer line-up with the y-axis.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>62</s> <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```r
function(r)symbols(x=1,c=r,i=F,xli=l<-c(-r-4,r+6),yli=l)
```

[Try it at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=plot_circle%3D%0Afunction(r)symbols(x%3D1%2Cc%3Dr%2Ci%3DF%2Cxli%3Dl%3C-c(-r-4%2Cr%2B6)%2Cyli%3Dl)%0Aplot_circle(5))

Comment: would `pty="s"` work instead of setting the `xlim` and `ylim` for the first 2? I was digging through the documentation for `par` but haven't had a chance to test it. It says `"s"` generates a square plotting region

Comment: @Giuseppe `par(pty="s")` should work but then it wouldn't satisfy the condition of 5 units of padding. In fact, from what I can see, only this answer satisfies the padding condition! Without `par(pty="s")` the circle depends on the output device being square, since the device will otherwise stretch.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks for the suggestion (I hadn't ever come across ```pty``` before).  I just tried it out, but it doesn't do what we want (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKjeJ.png)).  Top plot is my 68-byte answer, bottom plot is the 68-byte answer without ```ylim=l``` but with ```pty="s"```.  So ```pty="s"``` makes the plot square by stretching, not extending, the axis limits.  Drat!

Comment: @Therkel - welcome (back) to code-golf, and, in case you weren't aware, [R is the language of the month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19304/95126) this month (Sept 2020)!  As you obviously know R, how about giving a shot at a couple of R-golfs...?

Comment: @Therkel I completely missed the 5 padding requirement. Seems a bit random to be honest. At the least, you can use the order of variables in `plot` to get the first down to [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P600L7kkMz9Po0izICe/RKNIyzAzTsPQyjDVWN/SUlNHRylHSSfHRjdZQ7dI11SnSNtUUydH8/9/AA); presumably similar golfs would work for the others.

Comment: @Giuseppe - Thanks!  You've done it again!  I simply did not realise that you can use anonymous arguments for ```plot``` (except for ```x``` and ```y```).  How did you figure-out that 'type' is argument 3, and (even more amazingly) that 'xlim' and 'ylim' are arguments 4 and 5?  ```args(plot)``` gives ```function(x,y,...)``` and ```?plot``` doesn't even list 'xlim' and 'ylim'...!

Comment: well, I googled "R plot" and went to the first result from the stat.ethz.ch site (which I always do when googling R documentation), which luckily was the page for `plot.default`! The docs for `plot` say `plot.default` will be used for simple scatterplots, so I suppose I lucked out somewhat :-)

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2 & 3, 55 bytes

*-17 bytes thanks to @DigitalTrauma*
*-1 byte thanks to @Sisyphus*
*-2 bytes thanks to @ovs*

```
from turtle import*
def f(r):sety(-r);clear();circle(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehpLSoJCdVITO3IL@oRIsrJTVNIU2jSNOqOLWkUkO3SNM6OSc1sUgDSGcWAZlAqf//AQ)

[turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) is standard library included in Python 2 & 3. I came up with `turtle` idea as a almost first result in Googling "[graphics python](https://www.google.com/search?q=graphics+python)".

Comment: The question asks for user input, so you need to input radius r, then draw a circle of radius r.

Comment: @Razetime Thanks, corrected!

Comment: Just realized that just drawing circle gives non-centered result, added code for centering.

Comment: If window is allowed to be closed automatically after drawing is done, then `done()` can be removed from end of code, it just prevents window from closing.

Comment: so long as it displays the circle, even for a frame, there is no problem. I think you can remove int() from int(input()) as well.

Comment: `fd()` is an alias of `forward()`.  Also you can use `goto()` to set the start position: [60 bytes with the other suggestions](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehpLSoJCdVITO3IL@oRIuryDYzr6C0REOTq6AUSKTnl@RrGOjoFgH5KUB@cmZRck6qRpHm//8A)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma For me without `int()` doesn't work passing str r.

Comment: @Arty On my system, python3 requires the `int()`, python doesn't.

Comment: Just figured out that `sety` can be used instead of `goto`.

Comment: I think you can save a byte by making it a function submission instead: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehpLSoJCdVITO3IL@oRIsrJTVNIU2jSNOqoFRD07o4taRSQ7dI07ogBchLzixKzkkFSv7/DwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Sisyphus Thanks, updated!

Comment: This is a really cool approach, and I can't believe there aren't more turtle golfs in Python!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I came up with `turtle` solution as a first result in Googling "[graphics python](https://www.google.com/search?q=graphics+python)".

Comment: Instead of lifting the pen and putting it backdown, you can `clear()` the canvas after `sety`: `def f(r):sety(-r);clear();circle(r)` for -2

Comment: @ovs Thanks! Updated post for 55 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## LaTeX, 66 bytes

```tex
\input tikz\def\f#1{~\vfill\centering\tikz\draw circle(#1);\vfill}
```

I consider the "canvas" required by this challenge to be the default text area of a latex page. The code defines a macro `\f` that takes the radius in cm as an argument.

### Example Code

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\input tikz\def\f#1{~\vfill\centering\tikz\draw circle(#1);\vfill}

\begin{document}
\f{3}
\enddocument
```

Outputs a PDF:

[image]

Comment: How is the input given?

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Let me change it.

Answer (score 6):

## [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda r:circle((0,0),r)
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs43hyknMTUpJVCiySs4sSs5J1dAw0DHQ1CnS5OJK0zDUBAC5NAlx&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

#### Example

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>169</s> <s>166</s> <s>161</s> 160 bytes

Thanks to ceilingcat (x3) for the suggestions! I also changed the newlines in the header to spaces as they seem to work fine as separators (at least in Irfanview) and fixed a bug that got revealed when the array was put on the stack.

Generates an image in PBM format, as it's probably the simplest way to make a bitmap! For some reason, all the online PBM viewers that I tried don't seem to like the output file, but Irfanview and GIMP are fine with it.

```c
z;f(r,w){char s[(w=r*2+11)*w+1];float x=s[w*w]=!memset(s,48,w*w);for(;x<7;)s[z=round(sin(x+=1e-5)*r+r+5)+round(cos(x)*r+r+5)*w]=49;printf("P1 %d %d %s",w,w,s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5NasMwEIX3PoWaUNCfSx0S0qIoZ@jeZKHKliOQraJRKpOQq1dVXMq8xbxvmJmn60HrnK/C4MATuemzCghanGSgG9Y0hCbWnIRxXkU0S2gTTSf5NPYj9BED377xQogwPmAxH/aCQHuVwV@mDoOd8Mxk09c7QgMLbEfY30R7wPM/exzcvouvYKdo8OqjQc/dIljxVAqIuOe1nbS7dD06QOyc/Xw5H6uqLKBRlS@PRoVBc7Tkp7SYb4JuFUIGq@gtpowtjIjqnvPm9UcbpwbItRtznX4B)

Comment: Libreoffice shows the correct circle [image.](https://i.imgur.com/snbdhpO.png) Nice Answer.

Comment: Save 21 bytes with `z,x;f(r,w){char s[(w=r*2+11)*w+1];for(x=!memset(s,48,w*w);x<7e5;)s[z=sin(++x)*r+r+5+round(cos(x)*r+r+5)*w]=49;printf("P1 %d %d %s",w,w,s);}`. No need for the first `round` and to keep x below 7 (or 2π) .

Answer (score 5):

## T-SQL, 47 bytes

```sql
SELECT geometry::Point(0,0,0).STBuffer(r)FROM t
```

Input is taken via a pre-existing table *t* with float field *r*, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Uses SQL [geo-spatial functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), displayed in the SQL Management Studio results pane:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Desmos, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
xx+yy=rr
r
```

[Desmos it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ggztyhdfmz)

Comment: Is there a way to center the plot/zoom in desmos using code?

Comment: @Razetime if you've zoomed away from centre, press the home button.

Comment: I mean, for r=50, the circle extends outside the screen. is there a way to zoom to fit?

Comment: @Razetime use the - and + zoom buttons or scroll up/down

Comment: i mean, programatically.

Comment: @Razetime no. Desmos no do that

Comment: A similar solution might work with Matlab's `ezplot`, but I don't happen to have an interpreter at hand and tio (run as Octave) doesn't do graphics

Comment: MATL should work for that. It's available online.

Comment: What's wrong with \$r=1\$?

Comment: @Ausername there is nothing wrong with that. It's just that I didn't know that when I posted this, and someone else later claimed that answer.

Comment: +1, cool language, you can plot a polynomial in just one command

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
Graphics@*Circle
```

See [Wolfram documentation on Circle](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle.html)

for example here is a circle with center (0,0) and radius r=42

[image]

-6 bytes from @LegionMammal978

Comment: The specifications call for a single input, the radius. On the other hand, Mathematica should center the circle in the plot window automatically, regardless of the center.

Comment: @GregMartin "...or any other formula that will plot a circle according to the given parameters". Do you thing you you have a shortest solution? I don't think that `Circle[]` is acceptable, so this is the shortest way.

Comment: You could just use `Graphics@Circle@##&`, or shorter yet, `Graphics@*Circle`.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 yes, you're right..

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 96 bytes

```js
f=
v=>`<svg width=${s=v*2+12} height=${s}><circle r=${v} cx=${v+=6} cy=${v} stroke=#000 fill=none>`
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.innerHTML=f(+this.value)><div id=o>
```

Outputs an SVG(HTML5) image, which the snippet displays for you. If HTML5 is acceptable, then for 95 bytes:

```js
f=
v=>`<div style="width:${v*=2}px;height:${v}px;margin:6px;border:1px solid;border-radius:100%">`
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.innerHTML=f(+this.value)><div id=o>
```

Comment: feel free to use html5 for your main answer.

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB, <s>38</s> 37 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Tom Carpenter*

```matlab
ezpolar(@(x)r);axis((r+5)*cospi(1:4))
```

Input as variable `r` in workspace.
Output:
[image: output]

Comment: Ignore my previous deleted comments, forgot the circle had to be centred. You can save a byte with `ezpolar(@(x)r);axis((r+5)*cospi(1:4))`. The `cospi(1:4)` gives you `[-1 1 -1 1]` which can be multipled directly with `(r+5)` to get your limits array.

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, <sup><s>11</s> <s>8</s></sup> 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/98541)

```
Polar
Input r₁
ZSquare
```

Input is a string, and is stored as a function. This function is shown in polar coordinates, so it shows as a circle.

Output for `"4`:

[image: sniping target XD]

Comment: +1, looks like sniping target XD

Answer (score 4):

### [<>^v](https://github.com/Astroide/---v#v), 56 bytes

```
ƒ∆57±∑361i∆90v
v 0Ii(I<   ª <
]      ^
>¶°    ^
>1 æ∑  ^
```

##### Explanation

`ƒ` : toggle turtle visibility
`∆` : raise pen
`57`: push 57
`±` : negate
`∑` : turtle forward by top of stack
`361`: push 361 (360 + 1)
`i` : pop stack & store in variable `i`
`∆` : lower pen
`90`: push 90
`v` : send instruction pointer down
`<` : send instruction pointer left
`ª` : turtle rotate right by top of stack (90)
**start of loop**
`<` : send instruction pointer left
`I` : push value of variable `i`
`(` : decrement top of stack
`i` : pop & store in variable `i`
`I` : push value of variable `i`
`0` : push 0
`v` : send instruction pointer down
`]` : if top of stack is greater than or equal to second element of stack\

- `>` : send instruction pointer right
- `¶` : update display
- continue to **continue here**\

Else
`>` : send instruction pointer right
`1`: push 1
`æ` : turn left (top of stack) degrees
`∑` : go forward by top of stack
`^` : send instruction pointer up
**continue here**
`^` : send instruction pointer up
`^` : Idem, there to ensure trailing whitespace is not removed
go to **start of loop**

After drawing the circle, the program never halts to prevent the window from closing.

Screenshot below (Python Turtle Graphics is because the program does not set a title to the window and the interpreter is written in Python and uses Turtle for graphics) :
[image: screenshot]

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange)

Comment: does this take input?

Comment: @Razetime No, it doesn't

Comment: Just realized how stupid what I just said was. Didn't see the program ought to take a radius input. I'll update it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 74 bytes

-16 bytes thanbks to Aaron Miller!

```
func[r][d: r + 5 view compose/deep[base(2x2 * d)draw[circle(1x1 * d)(r)]]]
```

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 90 bytes

```
func[r][d: r + 5 view compose/deep[base(as-pair d * 2 d * 2)draw[circle(as-pair d d)(r)]]]
```

`f 200`

[image]

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcjBCoAgDADQX9lR6xAKXfoV2cHcAqFSJqV/v6B3fMKkejx3CoKBNhCYYYU3c4dUrloaL8Rcwx4bGz88TECWJPaQsqSTjRvuPyMWEVU/ "Red – Try It Online")

Comment: @AaronMiller Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>141</s> 123 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;r->new Frame(){{setSize(2*r+26,2*r+56);show();}public void paint(Graphics g){g.drawOval(13,43,2*r,2*r);}}
```

Output for \$n=100\$ (the second picture with added light grey background color is to verify the top padding):

[image] [image]

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.awt.*;     // Required import for Frame and Graphics
r->                    // Method with integer parameter and Frame return-type
 new Frame(){          //  Create the Frame
   {                   //   In an inner code-block:
     setSize(2*r       //    Set the width to 2 times the radius-input
             +26       //     + 2 times 8 pixels for the frame borders
                       //     + 2 times 5 pixels for the required padding
             2*r       //    Set the height to 2 times the radius-input
             +56);     //     + 2 times 8 pixels for the frame borders
                       //     + 30 pixels for the frame title-bar
                       //     + 2 times 5 pixels for the required padding
     show();}          //    And show the Frame at the end
   public void paint(Graphics g){
                       //   Overwrite its paint method to draw on
     g.drawOval(13,43, //    With 5,5 for the required padding as top-left
                       //    x,y-coordinate of the surrounding rectangle + the same 8+30
                       //    pixels adjustment for the frame and frame title-bar,
         2*r,2*r);}}   //    draw the circle with a size of 2 times the radius-input
```

Note: I cannot use `(r*=2),r,r,r` instead of `2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r` to save (3) bytes, because `r` has to be effectively final inside the inner Frame-class.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 158 bytes

```javascript
r=>document.write(`<p style="border-radius:50%;border:solid;position:fixed;width:${r*2}px;height:${r*2}px;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);">`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1dCsIwEISvIkXBihURBElsz9LYJHYlzYbN9kfEs8daH3wZvpmBmYcaVGwIAhfDJdkyUVlpbPrOeD6MBGy29TWsIj@dKbMbkjZUkNLQR3E@buQvEREdaBkwAgN6YWEyWo6guRXrF@1O7zDJ1sC95b9nDMuEM5YXYFI@WqROLOTUfF7Mxf4rucyqOk/pAw)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftyLdw70/) thanks to @Razetime

- Saved 1 thanks to @Razetime
- Saved 2 using template literals

Writes directly to the HTML a `p` element fixed positioned, centered with border radius 50%

Comment: This is better hosted on [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ftyLdw70/)

Comment: Yes @Razetime thanks, I tried but it's really hard from a phone :/

Comment: oh, gotcha. I think border-radius 50% is enough, so -1 byte.

Comment: The jsfiddle link just gives me a bouncing cloud with an infinity sign...  So (without having actually witnessed the output): does border-radius 50% satisfy the "must have a padding of 5 units or more on all sides" when r<10?

Comment: The circle is always at the center of the screen, due to top and left:50%

Comment: @Dominic van Essen to be honest it doesn't have any padding, it just prints a circle on the center of the available screen, problem is when 2*r is bigger than the screen but if it has to print a circle of n pixel radius bigger than the screen size there's no way it can fit inside it, the only way is to scale r which is a different r in my opinion, I hope that is acceptable

Answer (score 2):

### Shadertoy (GLSL), 142 bytes

```
void mainImage(out vec4 f,in vec2 v){vec2 S=iResolution.xy;vec2 u=v/S-vec2(0.5);u.y/=S.x/S.y;vec4 c;if(abs(length(u)-0.2)<8e-4)c=vec4(1);f=c;}
```

[Shadertoy link](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3ddcD8)

Output:

[image]

Comment: 85 bytes:   
    void mainImage(out vec4 f,in vec2 v){v-=vec2(400,225);f=vec4(abs(dot(v,v)-1e4)<1e2);}

Comment: My above code might not apply with the challenge, does print a circle though

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s><sup>96</sup></s> <s><sup>92</sup></s> 87 bytes

*Forgot to remove some extra whitespace for -4 bytes.*

*-5 bytes by using shorter type conversions and initializing and using `x` at the same time.*

```
draw to-pair x: r * 9 to-block append"circle "append mold to-pair x / 2 append" "mold r
```

No TIO link because `draw` doesn't seem to be implemented on TIO. However, you can copy [this](https://gist.github.com/AMiller42/e8477ef6ec0e4665c7996d5b8df72949) into the Red offline interpreter to output an image.

The first line is for defining a variable to be used for the canvas size. Multiplying by 9 might be a bit overkill, but it ensures enough padding around the circle. I couldn't figure out how to use variables in the block, so the second line builds the draw command bit by bit, essentially building the command `draw {x}x{x} [circle {x / 2}x{x / 2} {r}]`.

Example output for \$r = 10\$:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>59</strike> <strike>57</strike> <strike>55</strike> 51 byte

```
func[r][?(draw 2 * c: 5x5 + r reduce['circle c r])]
```

Try it [locally](https://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html).

-2 bytes thanks to [Aaron Miller](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/504997) spotting superfluous `as-pair`.

---

Output for \$r=50\$:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Great use of the tools provided by the GUI console!

Answer (score 2):

## 80186 DOS machine code, <s>76</s> <s>74</s> <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```
00000000: b8 13 00 cd 10 1e 68 00 a0 1f f7 df 8d 6d 02 01  ......h......m..
00000010: fd 31 c0 f7 df e8 20 00 f7 df 97 e8 1a 00 89 eb  .1.... .........
00000020: 39 df e8 0a 00 97 39 fb e8 04 00 75 e6 1f 7c 06  9.....9....u..|.
00000030: 01 fd 8d 6b 03 47 c3 e8 00 00 69 d8 40 01 fe 81  ...k.G....i.@...
00000040: a0 7d f7 df f7 d8 c3                             .}.....
```

A function which expects the radius in `di`. Forces DOS to graphics mode and doesn't bother to clean up.

I am mostly just excited about getting it working, I will hopefully find some ways to optimize.

Translation of the Go version of the Midpoint circle algorithm from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#Go).

- 2 bytes: branch once in `correct` instead of branching twice in the main function
- 2 bytes: reuse flags from `inc` for loop trigger.
- 1 byte: Fall through to `correct` when returning.

##### Commented assembly

```lisp
        ; nasm file.asm -f obj -o file.obj
        [cpu 186]
        global draw_circle
        ; args: di: radius
draw_circle:
        ; switch DOS to graphics mode
        mov     ax, 0x0013
        int     0x10
        ; set ds to point to the screen buffer
        push    ds
        push    0xA000
        pop     ds

        ;  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#Go
        ; di => x1
        neg     di
        ; bp => err
        lea     bp, [2 + di]
        add     bp, di
        ; ax => y1
        xor     ax, ax
.loop:
        neg     di
        ; x - x1, y + y1
        ; x + x1, y - y1
        call    set_pixel
        neg     di
        ; swap
        xchg    ax, di
        ; x + y1, y + x1
        ; x - y1, y - x1
        call    set_pixel
        ; ax: x1, di: y1
        
        ; save err to bx
        mov     bx, bp
        ; check y1
        ; we branch in correct
        cmp     di, bx
        call    correct
        ; swap back
        xchg    ax, di
        ; check x1, using the opposite order
        cmp     bx, di
        call    correct
        ; loop while x1 is negative
        ; the flags will be set from correct
        jnz     .loop
        ; restore ds segment
        pop     ds
        ; uncomment to wait for enter then switch to
        ; standard mode
        ; mov     ah, 0x08
        ; int     0x21
        ; mov     ax, 0x0003
        ; int     0x10
        ; Fallthrough to exit

        ; some helper functions to cut down the copy-paste
correct:
        ; The flags will be set to the comparison before
        ; calling
        jl      .skip
        ; err += 2 * ++di + 1
        add     bp, di
        lea     bp, [bp + di + 3]
        ; ++di
        inc     di
.skip:
        ret

        ; ax: y, di: x
set_pixel:
        ; run twice by semi-recursion
        call    .semirecurse
.semirecurse:
        ; ++byte[x + 160 + (320 * (y + 100))]
        imul    bx, ax, 320
        inc     byte[di + bx + 0x7DA0]
        ; negate both here
        neg     di
        neg     ax
        ret
```

with radius = 50, showing the disgusting exit:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Python + pygame, 110 bytes

```
r=int(input())
d=display
s=5+r
draw.circle(d.set_mode([s+s]*2),[99]*3,[s]*2,r,1)
d.update()
```

We only use `set_mode` once, so we can pass it as an argument to `draw.circle`.

It's almost impossible to golf in Pygame so this is probably the shortest it can get, although I could change `99` to 9.

Example for 250:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos, <s>10</s> 12 bytes

```
xx+yy=rr
r=1
```

[Desmos it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ggztyhdfmz)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 92 bytes

```perl
$r=$_;
$w=$r*2+11;
$_="P1 $w $w @{[map{($_%$w-$r-5)**2+($_/$w-$r-5)**2<$r**2?1:0}0..$w**2-1]}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lyFYl3lql3FalSMtI29DQWiXeVinAUEGlHIQcqqNzEwuqNVTiVVXKdVWKdE01tYDKgHx9JL4NUK@Wkb2hlUGtgZ6eSjmQo2sYW6v0/7@h6b/8gpLM/Lzi/7oFAA)

Circle with black filling. Put the 92 bytes above into program.pl and run like this:

```perl
echo 50 | perl -p program.pl > circle.pbm  # radius 50
feh circle.pbm                             # view with feh or other image viewer
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 131 bytes

```php
($f=imagecolorallocate)($i=imagecreate($d=10+$argn*2,$d),0,0,0);imageellipse($i,$d/2,$d/2,$d-10,$d-10,$f($i,9,9,9));imagepng($i,a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtbCoMwEEU3Mx8ZH5gI/RCVrmXQJA2MZki7/zQR5cKB@5KP5OUthQrcGg7ydoscEzHHjX4WFYQ7TrZ4BftqdAuU/NmMHezY6Sqcr5FlDvItq1CqYXzQG/3Q1W6qwvsjp68Z4ZzzS/8B)

Actually you cannot run it in online PHP testers because they disable the image functions. Saves the image in a file named "a". One byte could be saved using `imagegd` but I didn't know the "gd" format and couldn't open it to check if it works.

The circle is in very dark grey, but I consider it visible. If you don't, leave a comment and I'll edit, with one byte more `$f($i,99,0,0)` it's much clearer.

with `$f($i,9,9,9)`:

[image]

with `$f($i,99,0,0)`:

[image]

Comment: dark grey is different from black, so it's alright. I can see the circle.

Answer (score 1):

## HTML + Javascript, 98

### JavaScript: 85, HTML: 13

```js
F=r=>{C.width=C.height=r*2+16;c=C.getContext`2d`;c.arc(r+8,r+8,r,0,6.283);c.stroke()}

F(100)
```

```html
<canvas id=C>
```

To change r, change `r=100` to `r=/*place your value here*/`.

Comment: you need to provide a function or take the result of an `alert()`

Comment: @Razetime Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, entire iOS app, 152 bytes

`project.pbxproj` not included.

```swift
import SwiftUI
@main struct A:App{@State var s="1"
var body:some Scene{WindowGroup{VStack{TextField("",text:$s)
Circle().frame(width:.init(Int(s)!))}}}}
```

The unit for the radius is 0.5pt, which is either 1px or 1.5px depending on the device. The app crashes if you type something that isn't an integer.

Preview, with a radius of 50pt:

[image: 1]

#### Ungolfed

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "1"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $text)

            Circle()
                .frame(width: CGFloat(Int(text)!))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this take input?

Comment: No, it doesn’t respond to user interaction at all.

Comment: the question requires a method of input to scale the circle.

Comment: Oh, you’re right, I missed that. I can’t fix it now but I can get to it later today.

Answer (score 1):

### [ZX Spectrum BASIC](https://worldofspectrum.org/ZXBasicManual/zxmanchap17.html), 1, 3 or 6 bytes

Nothing beats BASIC computers with bitmap graphics that consider a case of honour to implement the built in CIRCLE command...

`CIRCLE x,y,r`

The command takes just one byte (though it is printed as the whole word), depending on what and how do you count the size, it can be 1 byte (the command itself), 3 bytes (the command and obligatory commas separating the articles; note that the space is only visual), 6 bytes (the command, commas and three already defined variables (or `PI`)).

[image: CIRCLE]

Comment: you must input radius and center it in the screen. x and y are not specified inputs, and must not be taken. predefined variables are not allowed in a submission.

Comment: @Razetime from the question: "Input can be taken in any acceptable form. (function params, variables, stdin...)" - and these are function (or procedure, if you prefer) parameters. Also, the original example does not use any inputs, but defines variables. I think some clarification is needed...

Comment: Ok, sorry, only one predefined variable is allowed. `r` is the only allowed input.  you must define your entire program to make sure that it does not use any input other than `r` (and center the circle).

Answer (score 1):

### PostScript, 69 bytes

```ps
currentpagedevice/PageSize get{2 div}forall
3 2 roll
0 360 arc stroke
```

Pass the radius on the command line:

```
gs -c 150 -- circle.ps
```

Displays output in a window, which then immediately closes! Add `showpage` for a persistent window. Centering the output took more bytes than I had hoped...

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>132</s> 128 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

```c
main(r,w,i,j){scanf("%d",&r);i=w=r+9;for(printf("P5\n%d%1$d\n1\n",2*w);i--+w;)for(j=w;j--+w;)putchar(abs((i*i+j*j)*2-r*r)<2*r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpLCsIwFADvEqzkCzbiQmLu4AGyiQnVF/C1vFayEM8eI24Ghplk7im19oyAnHTVoIt4rynixNmQmd6TcOCrJ3V200x8IcCtt@sp4JCHcZcDjgGZtrL20xhVnfiNxVdX/rq8tvSIxONt5RwkqCKLkNaQJHGxHe7T2vHwBQ)

Outputs a [PGM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) image.
A unit corresponds to `sqrt(2)` pixels.

Answer (score 1):

### Applesoft BASIC, 106 bytes

```
0INPUTR
1HGR
2HCOLOR=3
3D=0
4HPLOTR*COS(D)+140,R*SIN(D)+96TOR*COS(D+.1)+140,R*SIN(D+.1)+96
5D=D+0.1
6GOTO4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Desmos, 3 bytes

```
r=1
```

Simply entering `r`, in my concern, doesn't work, but entering `r=0` automatically makes it a slider.

r=0 doesn't create a circle. Sorry about that.

Comment: Pasting this into desmos doesn't seem to produce a circle.

Comment: @WheatWizard fixed

Answer (score 0):

## Robocompass, 16 bytes

```
arc(0,0,a,0,360)
```

Where you have to define a before that as input.

Comment: I don't think this is [a permitted input method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

Comment: @WheatWizard but as far as I am concerned it is the only way in robocompass. :-(