# Draw the flag of Bangladesh

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

The flag of Bangladesh is very simple. It looks like below:

[image]

The flag will be in bottle green (#006a4e) and rectangular in size in the proportion of length to width of 10:6, with a red circle in near middle. The red circle (#f42a41) will have a radius of one-fifth of the length of the flag. This image will help you to understand the proportions properly:

[image]

In this Graphical output challenge, you need to draw the flag of Bangladesh like first image. Standard loopholes apply, Shortest code wins.

Resolution cannot be 0px, or `echo` style answers not supported.

Minimum resolution is `286*176`

Comment: Related: [Plot a centered circle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211460/plot-a-centered-circle/211905#211905). I adapted my answer from there

Comment: Next challenge: draw the flag of Bhutan.

Comment: So basically every attempt of mine to center a circle in a div 

Comment: @Mark Mathematica, 23 bytes: `"BT"~CountryData~"Flag"`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 23 bytes

¯\__(ツ)_/¯   of course there is a built in for this...

```
"BD"~CountryData~"Flag"
```

but you can also get the same result with...

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 78 bytes

```
Graphics@{(c=RGBColor)@"#006a4e",{0,0}~Cuboid~{5,3},c@"#f42a41",Disk[{9,6}/4]}
```

[image]

-8 bytes {first code) thanks to @Makonede for "Bangladesh" to "BD"
-4 bytes (second code) thanks to @att

Comment: As usual, there's a built-in for this

Comment: I am gonna ban Mathematica for my next challenges :P

Comment: Does `BD` work instead of `Bangladesh`? If so, you can save 8 bytes

Comment: @Makonede yes, I think you are right!

Comment: 78: `Graphics@{(c=RGBColor)@"#006a4e",{0,0}~Cuboid~{5,3},c@"#f42a41",Disk[{9,6}/4]}`

Answer (score 34):

## SVG, 67 bytes

By tweaking the viewBox, we can take advantage of the fact that the stroke of a shape has a default width. That avoids creating any element for the background.

```html
<svg viewBox=-.9,-.6,2,1.2><circle r=.9 fill=#f42a41 stroke=#006a4e
```

Comment: The first comma is unnecessary. `viewBox=-.9-.6,2,1.2` will also work

Comment: @r3mainer There's disagreement on whether "-" is a valid delimeter outside of "path". removing that comma in the viewbox will break the snippet in firefox.

Comment: Ah, ok then :-)

Comment: If it works on at least one implementation, it's acceptable here. Removing the `,` works on Chrome 89 on Windows 10, so even if it breaks in Firefox, it's still an acceptable golf

Comment: nit: This is HTML + SVG, standalone SVG needs the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` attribute and doesn't offer the nice parsing recuperation that allows unclosed elements and unquoted attributes

Comment: Actually the HTML thing is more than a nit... For it to be rendered correctly as a standalone HTML file, you'd need to at least close the `<circle>` opening tag. It seems to work in StackSnippets because they do wrap your code into a valid HTML base markup. So for the same number of bytes, a real HTML + SVG solution would be `<svg viewBox=-.9-.6,2,1.2><circle r=1 fill=#f42a41 stroke=#006a4e>` which works in Webkit + Blink browsers, as a .html file.

Answer (score 28):

## SVG in HTML, 74 bytes

```html
<svg viewBox=-9,-6,20,12 style=background:#006a4e><circle r=4 fill=#f42a41
```

-8 bytes by [Joey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15/joey)

Comment: Technically HTML+SVG (or HTML5), as this is not valid SVG and will fail to render as an `.svg` file. You also need HTML's block element behavior for the background to work.

Comment: You can also shorten it quite a bit with a more clever viewBox: `<svg viewBox=-9,-6,20,12 style=background:#006a4e><circle r=4 fill=#f42a41`

Answer (score 28):

## Python3 + [Turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html), <s>112</s> 84 bytes

```python
from turtle import*
setup(286,176)
bgcolor("#006a4e")
ht()
bk(14)
dot(114,"#f42a41")
```

-28B thanks to Digital Trauma

Can't try it online but here is how it looks:
[image: Turtle Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: Some [improvements](https://tio.run/##Dcg7DoAgDADQnVMYXIpxsNig1/EDavyUYB08PfrGF19Z@WpzDonPQp4khy@2M3KSSt1engi2dzV2zqhxmfjgBLpsGjeQ10atAv/vgGTUzAKIVOsykB0Itcn5Aw) for you

Comment: DigitalTrauma & RedwolfPrograms thank you very much!

Answer (score 20):

## HTML, 110 bytes

```html
<div style=padding:10%35%10%25%;background:#006a4e><nav style=padding:50%;background:#f42a41;border-radius:50%
```

-1 bytes by Adám

Fun fact: percentage values on `padding-top` / `padding-bottom` follow the container’s width (not height).

Comment: You don't need the trailing `;}`

Comment: Using `p` instead of `div` saves you a few bytes.

Comment: Remove `;}` seems not work (at least on above snippet) But remove `}` only works fine. Using `p` will introduce an extra `padding-bottom` which cause the circle moves to wrong position.

Comment: [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPQ9DUQUOB02) looks fine to me.

Comment: Is there any significance to using `<nav` rather than `<div`?

Answer (score 15):

## Bash + ImageMagick, <s>80</s> 79 characters

```bash
convert -size 500x300 xc:#006a4e -draw 'fill #f42a41 circle 225,150,225,250' x:
```

Thanks to

- [Chris Down](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6534/chris-down) for pointing out word I missed in man bash: “a word *beginning* with `#` causes that word and all remaining characters on that line to be ignored”

Sample output:
[image: flag of Bangladesh]

Comment: If you interpret ImageMagick to be a scripting language, arguably it goes down to 72 ;)

Comment: Well, ImageMagick can certainly be used as programming language when you pass it code as FX expression. But if I read the meta question [Is ImageMagick a programming language?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/is-imagemagick-a-programming-language), my solution looks quite pathetic compared to that.

Comment: Nice answer! You can remove a byte by omitting the backslash before the `#`, as `bash` doesn't consider octothorpes within a word to be comment starters.

Comment: Me shocked.  Thank you, @ChrisDown.

Comment: Here are a couple of other potential improvements I see to save three more characters, assuming I didn't miss any constraints. :-) One is if you use `300x180`, the `y0` passed to circle saves one character (it becomes 90). The second is that you can, instead of specifying the bottom-most point of the circle, specify the northwest point for the smallest possible `x1,y1`. So doing something like `ao = sqrt(4.5^2+3^2); ab = a0 - 2`, where `ab/a0 == x/3 == y/4.5` (scaling for 300*180 with factor 30), you can ultimately pass `135,90,85,57` as the arguments to `circle`, saving three characters. :-)

Answer (score 12):

### CSS, <s>128</s> <s>107</s> <s>104</s> 89 bytes

```css
*{background:radial-gradient(200px at 45%,#f42a41 50%,#006a4e 0)0 0/500px 300px no-repeat
```

For best results run the code snippet and then click Full Page. Edit: Worked out that setting the background position and size works better than setting the body size. Saved 3 bytes thanks to @sech1p. Saved 15 bytes by copying @dingledooper's radial gradient.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes using `*` instead of `body`

Answer (score 11):

## [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript), <s>114</s> 95 bytes

Code:

```
0 .42 .31 setrgbcolor
0 0 300 180 rectfill
.96 .16 .25 setrgbcolor
135 90 60 0 360 arc fill
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: ```closepath``` and ```showpage``` can be deleted

Comment: @bartyslartfast Thanks, that removed 19 bytes.

Answer (score 10):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 101 bytes

```
Red[Needs:'view]view[base 500x300 0.106.78
draw[pen 244.42.65 fill-pen 244.42.65 circle 225x150 100]]
```

[image: Flag of Bangladesh, drawn in Red]

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>143</s> <s>111</s> <s>108</s> 92 bytes

```r
plot(0:9,,"n",as=1)
rect(0,0,10,6,,,"#006a4e",NA)
symbols(4.5,3,2,f=NA,bg="#f42a41",i=F,a=T)
```

[Try it on rrdr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=plot(0%3A9%2C%2C%22n%22%2Cas%3D1)%0Arect(0%2C0%2C10%2C6%2C%2C%2C%22%23006a4e%22%2CNA)%0Asymbols(4.5%2C3%2C2%2Cf%3DNA%2Cbg%3D%22%23f42a41%22%2Ci%3DF%2Ca%3DT))

*-32 bytes after looking at [@Dominic's answer to related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211475/55372)

-3 bytes thanks to [@Frédéric](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56131/fr%c3%a9d%c3%a9ric)*

Slighlty ungolfed to show full argument names (R allows partial matching):

```r
plot(x=0:9,y=NULL,type="n",asp=1)
rect(0,0,10,6,col="#006a4e",border=NA)
symbols(4.5,3,circles=2,fg=NA,bg="#f42a41",inches=F,add=T)
```

[image: result image]

Comment: `rect(0,0,10,6,c="#006a4e",b=NA)` can be replaced with `rect(0,0,10,6,,,"#006a4e",NA)` for -2 bytes and the `NA` in the 1st line by either `T` ort `F` for a whopping -1 byte

Comment: @Frédéric, thanks. I chose `T`, because with the `F` the dot was "peeking" from behind the rectangle :)

Comment: And then I changed the approach :P

Answer (score 9):

## Perl 5, 89 bytes

Using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for Linux-like command terminals. [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) in Windows should also work:

```
print"\33[0;3",($_%286-129)**2+($_/286-88)**2<3442?"1m#":"2m#",$_%286?"":"\n"for 1..50336
```

Run it in a terminal like this to get a big or small flag respectively in ansi colors or via a [.ppm image file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example) that can show the flag using most image viewers or web browsers:

```
perl -e'print"\33[0;3",($_%286-129)**2+($_/286-88)**2<3442?"1m#":"2m#",$_%286?"":"\n"for 1..50336'
perl -e'print"\33[0;3",($_%72-32)**2+($_/72-22)**2<215?"1m##":"2m##",$_%72?"":"\n"for 1..3168'
perl -E'say"P3 286 176 255 ",map 3442>($_%286-129)**2+($_/286-88)**2?"244 42 65 ":"0 106 78 ",1..50336' > flag.ppm
```

Answer (score 8):

## C + stb_image_write, <s>296</s> <s>288</s> <s>278</s> 270  bytes

```c
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include"stb_image_write.h"#include<math.h>
main(i){char p[151008];for(i=0;i<151008;i+=3){p[i]=0;p[i+1]=106;p[i+2]=78;if(pow(i/3%286-129,2)+pow(i/3/286-88,2)<3481)p[i]=244,p[i+1]=42,p[i+2]=65;}stbi_write_bmp("b.bmp",286,176,3,p);}
```

Outputs a BMP image called b.bmp:

[image]

Thanks to MerseyViking for the suggestion about removing `sqrt`

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c) page for ways you can golf your program

Comment: You can get rid of the sqrt by comparing the pow() sum against 3481

Answer (score 7):

## [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), 95 bytes

```html
<p style="width:500;height:300;background:radial-gradient(200px at 45%,#f42a41 50%,#006a4e 0)">
```

[Try it online!](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPQTJHFVBSWQ)

Comment: Nice radial gradient!

Answer (score 7):

## Basic (Tandy CoCo3 specifically), 109 Bytes

Firstly, hopefully there isn't a 'hard fast' rule on the exact color when the target computer only has a palette of 64 total... :-) I got as close as I could. I used the darkest green available and the 2nd darkest red.

Also, putting a CoCo3 in graphic mode doesn't "stay" unless you put some kind of pause at the end - but at 0.89 MHz it draws slowly enough you can see the result before it disappears back to text mode.

```
HSCREEN1:PALETTE1,2:PALETTE2,32:HCOLOR1,3:HLINE(0,0)-(299,179),PSET,BF:HCIRCLE(134,89),60,2:HPAINT(99,89),2,2
```

That said, if you did want to "press Enter to erase" and make it re-runnable without retyping in the line, it'll cost 9 bytes:

```
0 HSCREEN1:PALETTE1,2:PALETTE2,32:HCOLOR1,3:HLINE(0,0)-(299,179),PSET,BF:HCIRCLE(134,89),60,2:HPAINT(99,89),2,2:INPUTK
```

then type 'RUN'. Here's a screenshot of the result (emulated via VCC 2.1.0c on Server 2016):

[image]

The resolution of the flag is 300x180; the resolution of the video mode is 320x192, hence the (default) brighter green border on the edges.

Lastly, the program technically takes less bytes than I specified as it's tokenized, but I don't feel like doing that math.

Answer (score 7):

## Gnuplot, <del>147</del> <del>140</del> <del>137</del> <del>120</del> 112 bytes

```
se si rat-2
se xr[0:20]
se yr[0:6]
uns ti
uns ke
uns bor
p'-'w cir fs s fc rgb var
9 3 99 27214
9 3 4 16001601
e
```

Written out neatly:

```
# set length unit ratio on 2:1
set size ratio -2

# set axis ranges
set xrange[0:20]
set yrange[0:6]

# make it look less like a chart
unset tics
unset key
unset border

# plot inline data series (everything on the next lines, up to an 'e')
# data cx cy radius color (rgb, decimal)
p '-' with cirles fillstyle solid fillcolor rgb variable
9 3 99 27214
9 3 4 16001601
e
```

Result in the 'qt' terminal:
[image: Bangladesh flag, rendered using Gnuplot]

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 129 bytes

```php
($f=imagecolorallocate)($i=imagecreate(500,300),0,106,78);imagefilledellipse($i,225,150,200,200,$f($i,244,32,65));imagepng($i,a);
```

You cannot try it online as online testers logically disable image creation functions.
Here is the result (original file is called "a", I added the extension for the import)

[image]

Comment: Why have you set `$f` to `imagecolorallocate`? Can't you save 7 bytes by using it directly?

Comment: @CJDennis because it is used a second time, without it in a variable it would be 11 bytes more: `imagecolorallocate($i=imagecreate(500,300),0,106,78);imagefilledellipse($i,225,150,200,200,imagecolorallocate($i,244,32,65));imagepng($i,a);`

Comment: Oh, I see! You're using it immediately after assigning it! That is clever after all!

Comment: @CJDennis this syntax only works in PHP 7+ though, in 5.6 you'll have a `syntax error, unexpected '('` ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [p5.js](https://editor.p5js.org/), 97 bytes

```javascript
setup=x=>createCanvas(300,180)+background(0,106,78)+fill(244,42,65)+noStroke()+circle(135,90,120)
```

Comment: Replace `setup` with `draw` like in my submission to save a character. I didn't see this one when I first submitted.

Answer (score 4):

## Python + Pygame, 124 bytes

```py
from pygame import*
s=display.set_mode((286,176))
s.fill((0,106,78))
draw.circle(s,(244,42,65),(128,86),57)
display.update()
```

I haven't used Pygame in a long time, so I'm probably missing something obvious here (like setting the background of the window directly) but it's not the shortest answer overall either.

*-7 bytes thanks to @tsh's suggestion*
*-31 bytes thanks to @ChrisH and @Sadap*, wow I really need to learn Pygame again

Comment: Is `from pygame import*` works?

Comment: @tsh Oh yeah, then we get `draw` instead of `p.draw`.

Comment: I’m not in front of my computer. And I had not tested these codes. Is while 1 required to make it work? May I move 2 draw statements out from while loop?

Comment: use [s.fill()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) for the green part

Comment: and if you do `n=286,176` on a new line, call `set_mode(n)` and `draw.rect(..., (0,0,*n)` you can save even more bytes
EDIT: this is useless when using my other idea

Comment: @Sadap wow how could I have missed `s.fill`? Probably because I used to make all my games on a black background...

Comment: Lose the `while` ...line and 3 indents, put `a=input()` at the end for -2. That's if you need it to hold and not just flash up

Comment: @ChrisH thanks! really need to learn pygame again

Comment: 122 bytes https://tio.run/##DcpBCsMgEADAu6/IcS2LRGvUS95SJJpW0CpqKL7e5jpMGf2Tv885z5rTUsbbJr@EVHLtD@J2F1qJdpC2O9Z8f6XsPIAwCrlWlJLGzhAjwIp8VajNTa7aHztCPaKHhiCkRClQbRSBC4NGUdz03dhVnO0e6Jx/

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby with Shoes, 87 characters

```ruby
Shoes.app(width:500,height:300){background'006a4e'
stroke fill'f42a41'
oval 125,50,200}
```

Sample output:

[image: flag of Bangladesh]

Answer (score 3):

## HTML/CSS, 168 bytes

```
<div><div style=left:125;top:50;width:200;height:200;background:#f42a41;border-radius:50%><style>div{position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:500;height:300;background:#006a4e
```

You can try it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPU3SVQLA5X1) (doesn't seem to work as a snippet, for whatever reason...)

-1 byte thanks to Adám by removing the `}` at the end of the style block
-2 bytes thanks to Manish Kandu
-12 bytes thanks to pxeger
-13 bytes thanks to Neil

Comment: No need for that trailing `}`

Comment: [-1 by changing `border-radius:100px` to `border-radius:100%`](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPQ96E1XXGB9)

Comment: I think it works if you remove the `#` from the color hexes, saving 2 bytes.

Comment: [A further -2 by removing the quotes](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPQ98HE92WWC)

Comment: [`background-color` -> `background:#`](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPQ99PDK3M6V)

Comment: Actually, it can be `border-radius:50%`: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPQ9AIPORDH3

Comment: If you use `div` instead of `p` you don't need to override the margin and padding.

Comment: CSS Battle thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/) + [LÖVE/Love2D](https://love2d.org/), <del>176</del> 160 bytes

```lua
l=love;g=l.graphics;c=255;l.window.setMode(500,300)function l.draw()g.setBackgroundColor(0,106/c,78/c)g.setColor(244/c,42/c,65/c)g.circle('fill',225,150,100)end
```

-16 bytes thanks to [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You know that 0 / 255 = 0, right? And better use a `g=l.graphics` variable too.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3

I tried different solutions, here are my two best attempts...

### Python + turtle, 113 bytes

*Thanks to @Sadap to give me some hints on an "alternative" use of the turtle :)*

```python
from turtle import*
s=Screen()
s.screensize(300,180,'#006a4e')
s.setup(305,183)
ht()
setx(-15)
dot(120,'#f42a41')
```

[image: python + turtle]

Commented code:

```python
from turtle import*
# initialize a new window
s=Screen()
# define the turtle drawing area, with thee green background
s.screensize(300,180,'#006a4e')
# setup the size of the window
# slightly bigger than the drawing area, to avoid the scroll bars
s.setup(305,183)
# hide turtle default image
ht()
# from the center of the image, move to the left
# center of the circle
setx(-15)
# draw the red circle
dot(120,'#f42a41')
```

---

### Python + tkinter, 132 bytes

```python
from tkinter import*  
c=Canvas(Tk(),bg='#006a4e',width=300,height=180)
c.create_oval(75,30,195,150,fill='#f42a41',width=0)
c.pack()
```

[image: python + tkinter]

Commented code:

```python
from tkinter import*
# initialize a new window, setting the background color and the size 
c=Canvas(Tk(),bg='#006a4e',width=300,height=180)
# draw the red circle
c.create_oval(75,30,195,150,fill='#f42a41',width=0)
# add the circle to the canvas
c.pack()
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), <s>230</s> 201 bytes

[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/518572657)
-26 thanks to @att, who used pen size to skip the lengthy circle formula!

Scratchblocks can't understand that hex values are literally what the value should be, and incorrectly displays a color. Visually, changing `set[C v]to[#123abc` to `set pen color to(#123abc` would work in Scratchblocks (and save bytes in the process), but due to Scratch's HSL system, such a color cannot be reached without hacks. Using the built-in eyedrop tool, we can get close (almost indistinguishable to the human eye) but it is only an approximation. Alternatively, <s>23</s> 15 blocks.

```
when gf clicked
go to x:(240)y:(
erase all
set pen size to(288
set[C v]to(27214
set pen color to(C
pen down
set x to(-240
set[C v]to[#f42a41
set x to(-24
set pen size to(192
set pen color to(C
pen down
```

Comment: [206 bytes](https://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch3&script=define%0Ago%20to%20x%3A%28240%29y%3A%28-48%0Aerase%20all%0Aset%20pen%20size%20to%28192%0Aset%5BC%20v%5Dto%5B%23006a4e%0Aset%20pen%20color%20to%28C%0Apen%20down%0Aset%20x%20to%28-240%0Aset%20y%20to%2848%0Aset%20x%20to%28240%0Aset%5BC%20v%5Dto%5B%23f42a41%0Ago%20to%20x%3A%28-24%29y%3A%28%0Aset%20pen%20color%20to%28C%0Apen%20down), 16 blocks

Comment: [204](https://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch3&script=define%0Ago%20to%20x%3A%28240%29y%3A%28-48%0Aerase%20all%0Aset%20pen%20size%20to%28192%0Aset%5BC%20v%5Dto%2827214%0Aset%20pen%20color%20to%28C%0Apen%20down%0Aset%20x%20to%28-240%0Aset%20y%20to%2848%0Aset%20x%20to%28240%0Aset%5BC%20v%5Dto%5B%23f42a41%0Ago%20to%20x%3A%28-24%29y%3A%28%0Aset%20pen%20color%20to%28C%0Apen%20down)

Answer (score 3):

## stacked, 93 bytes

```
400 setwidth 240 setheight'#006a4e'setbg'#f42a41'allstyle'370px Arial'font 69 226 to'●'text
```

[Online interpreter.](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html) Here's the output generated (Firefox, latest version):

[image: picture of bangladesh flag generated by stacked program]

Or, a screenshot of the webpage:

[image: screenshot of the program and bangladesh flag it generates]

### Explanation

Simply initializes the canvas with appropriate dimensions, sets the appropriate background color, and then draws a bullet character of the correct font height and location. We have to do this because stacked has no native way of drawing circles arbitrarily. The correctness of these arbitrary values can be verified with the following program, which draws a square on the lower-right quadrant of where the circle ought to be:

```
400 setwidth 240 setheight'#006a4e'setbg'#f42a41'allstyle'370px Arial'font 69 226 to'●'text

'white' allstyle
180 120 to
[80 go 90 turn] 4*
```

[image: bangladesh flag with white measuring square on lower right quadrant]

Answer (score 3):

## HTML / Pug + Tailwind, 96 bytes

```
.w-80.py-8.pl-20(style='background:#006a4e')
 .rounded-full.w-32.h-32(style='background:#f42a41')
```

[Test](https://jsitor.com/26bCEpc2c)

## HTML / Pug + Tailwind, slightly changed colors, 64 bytes

```
.w-80.py-8.pl-20.bg-green-800
 .rounded-full.w-32.h-32.bg-red-600
```

[Test](https://jsitor.com/yyuCSEocV)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 110 bytes

```lisp
#lang slideshow
(pin-over(colorize(filled-rectangle 300 180)'(0 106 78))75 30(colorize(disk 120)'(244 42 65)))
```

[Can't try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYu7CoQwEAB7v2LB4rKFEGN8/I4kqy4uRhK5A38@5iqrgWEmzm6nK@da5mOFJOwpbeFXqZOPJnwpKhckRL5JLSxCvonkrtIKQac1tJPGjyrUA4wT4tgX/T6e0w6t@TfGWrAGhh4Rc34A), but here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## FLTK, 135 characters

```
Function{}{}{Fl_Window{}{xywh{0 0 500 300}box BORDER_BOX color 0x6a4eff}{Fl_Box{}{xywh{125 50 200 200}box OFLAT_BOX color 0xf42a41ff}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
Function {} {} {
    Fl_Window {} {
        xywh {0 0 500 300}
        box BORDER_BOX
        color 0x6a4eff
      } {
        Fl_Box {} {
            xywh {125 50 200 200}
            box OFLAT_BOX
            color 0xf42a41ff
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

[image: flag of Bangladesh]

Answer (score 2):

## p5.js, <s>105</s> <s>98</s> 96 bytes

```
draw=x=>createCanvas(300,180)+background(0,106,78)+noStroke()+fill(244,42,65)+circle(135,90,120)
```

Try it in the editor [here](https://editor.p5js.org/).

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript + HTML, <s>167</s> 153

### Javascript: <s>154</s> 140, HTML: 13

```js
C.width=w=300
C.height=h=180 // 300 * 0.6
with(C.getContext`2d`)fillStyle="#006a4e",fillRect(0,0,w,h),fillStyle="#f42a41",arc(.45*w,.3*w,.2*w,0,7),fill()
```

```html
<canvas id=C>
```

-14 characters from @Ismael Miguel

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using `with()`, like this: `with(C.getContext`2d`)fillStyle="#006a4e",fillRect(0,0,w,h),fillStyle="#f42a41",arc(0.45*w,0.3*w,0.2*w,0,7),fill()`. You can also assign the `w` variable like this: `C.width=w=300`. If you don't mind putting everything in a single line, you can just do this: `C.width=w=300,C.height=h=0.6*w;with(C.getContext`2d`)fillStyle="#006a4e",fillRect(0,0,w,h),fillStyle="#f42a41",arc(0.45*w,0.3*w,0.2*w,0,7),fill()`. The `;` can be replaced with a newline for no size difference. In total, this saves 9 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), <s>64</s> 61 bytes

```
r=rgb(244,42,65)
g=rgb(0,106,78)
-9<=x<=11\{yy<36\}
xx+yy<=16
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tj1ipkdqvw)

*-3 bytes thanks to Aiden Chow*

Answer (score 0):

## Desmos, 66 bytes

This:

```
r=rgb(244,42,65)
g=rgb(0,106,78)
-9≤x≤11\left\{yy≤36\right\}
xx+yy≤16
```

This is longer than the other one, but that other one didn't work, as `\left` and `\right` seems to be needed.

Comment: This doesn't work when pasted in.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 82 bytes

```perl
say"P6 300 180 255",map$=>((135-$_%300)**2+(90-$_/300)**2)**.5?".*A":".jN",0..54e3
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoic2F5XCJQNiAzMDAgMTgwIDI1NVwiLG1hcCQ9PigoMTM1LSRfJTMwMCkqKjIrKDkwLSRfLzMwMCkqKjIpKiouNT9cIvQqQVwiOlwiXHUwMDAwak5cIiwwLi41NGUzIiwiYXJncyI6Ii1NNS4xMC4wIiwibWltZSI6ImltYWdlL3gtcG9ydGFibGUtYml0bWFwIn0=)

Generates a PBM file by going through every co-ordinate and checking if the current pixel is within the circle, outputting the values for green or red respectively.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pikchr](https://pikchr.org/home/doc/trunk/homepage.md), 75 bytes

```
box ht.45fill 27214 color off
circle at-3/80,0rad.15fill 0xf42a41 color off
```

### Output

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 112.32 69.12">
<path d="M2,66L110,66L110,2L2,2Z" style="fill:rgb(0,106,78);"></path>
<circle cx="50" cy="34" r="21.6" style="fill:rgb(244,42,65);"></circle>
</svg>
```